# How to generate case class with annotation using ScalaXB

Tags: scala, jaxb, sbt, scala-xml, scalaxb

I am using the ScalaXB plugin to convert XSD files to Scala case classes and it is working fine but is there any way to add `javax.xml.bind.annotation` with it?

The reason I need is to marshal/unmarshal XML to generated classes and I am using `JAXB` but it is giving me the error that generated classes do not have a no-arg default constructor.

If not is there any other library to convert XSD files to Java files in sbt? I found `sbt-xjc` but I think it is not in active development.

File Generated from scalaxb

```scala
// Generated by <a href="http://scalaxb.org/">scalaxb</a>.
package generated

case class EmployeeType(FirstName: String,
  LastName: String,
  Age: Int,
  Email: String)
```

For parsing I am using Jaxb

```scala
  import javax.xml.bind._
  import java.io.StringReader

  def unmarshalXML[T](xmlString: String)(implicit tag: reflect.ClassTag[T]): Option[T] = {
    try {
      val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(tag.runtimeClass)
      val unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller()
      val instance = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString)).asInstanceOf[T]
      Some(instance)
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception =>
        ex.printStackTrace()
        None
    }
  }
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
generated.EmployeeType does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at generated.EmployeeType
```

Comment: Could you show what's the code that is throwing that error and what's the full error message? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.

Highlight: Don't use JAXB for marshaling and unmarshalling. Instead, use `scalaxb` only.

When we generate file using `scalaxb` it generates 2 extra files named: `scalaxb .scala` under package `scalaxb` and `xmlprotocol.scala` unded `generated` package. `scalaxb.scala` contains the required method to perform necessary operation on XML. For example,

We can use `fromXML` and `toXML` method for marshaling and unmarshalling.

```scala
import scalaxb
import generated._
import scala.xml.XML

val xmlElem = XML.loadString(xmlString)
val employeeType = scalaxb.fromXML[EmployeeType](xmlElem)
val backToXMLString = scalaxb.toXML[EmployeeType(employeeType, "EMPLOYEETYPE", generated.defaultScope)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).